# Проблема с promise'ами в ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Здравствуйте, вот в чем заключается проблема: когда я через `API` беру данные с сайта с помощью `axios`, подключаю этот файл к компоненту, в компоненте записываю результат функции запроса к `API` в новую переменную в `state`, то туда записывается `pending Promise`, а через секунду `promise` обновляется и получает в `[[PromiseValue]]` объект с данными, так вот как записать этот объект в переменную из `state`, а не пустой promise?

Код прилагается:

```
var axios = require('axios');

export default function getWeatherData( town ) {
  const SITE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather";
  const PRIVATE_ID = "************";

  let request = `${SITE_URL}?q=${town}&APPID=${PRIVATE_ID}`;

  return axios.get(request)
    .then(r => r.data);

}
```

А также код компонента:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import getWeatherData from './api/getWeather';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    weatherData: getWeatherData('Kiev')
  } 


  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.state.weatherData)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <h1>Hello world</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Скрин из консоли: [image]

Comment: Не понял. Promise всегда вернет promise. Если нужно значение, то надо его куда-то передать в блоке .then

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите получить значение r.data при монтировании компонента? Но асинхронный запрос не успевает завершиться до монтирования компонента. И надо изменить state компонента после получения r.data

Вариант 1. Поместить getWeatherData внутрь App и делать setState внутри блока .then

```
.then((r) => {
    this.setState({
        weatherData: r.data
    })
}
```

Вариант 2. Использовать любую методику с единым хранилищем состояния flux/redux и т.д. и в блоке .then вызывать диспетчер с действием изменения города в App

Answer (score 1):

Если не использовать никаких оберток а просто React, то логика для работы с начальным фетчем обычно примерно такая:

1. Инициализируем чем-нибудь состояние скажем null.

   ```
   state = {weatherData: null}
   ```
2. В ничего не отрисовываем если данных нет (можно конечно начальный каркас отрисовать если хочется).

   ```
   render(){
      if(this.state.weatherData === null){
        return null;
      }
   }
   ```
3. В componentDidMount вызываем нашу асинхронную операцию операцию по получению данных, и когда она завершится соответственно меняем state;

   ```
   componentDidMount(){
       this.getWeatherData().then(weatherData => this.setState({weatherData: weatherdata})
   }
   ```

Это самый простой подход для иллюстрации принципа. Он рабочий, но в сложных приложениях обычно поверх наворочено пара уровней абстракции вроде взаимодействия с хранилищем и ряд мелких ui-оптимизаций